# What is the main difference between CRCW and EREW in PRAM model?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, synchronous, processor, thread-synchronization

In the PRAM model, multiple processors act synchronously to execute the same command on different sets of data.

There are two types of **read/write** mode for each algorithm;

1. Concurrent (Concurrent **Read** & Concurrent **Write**)
2. Exclusive (Exclusive **Read** & Exclusive **Write**)

What I find hard to understand is what exactly is the difference between these two modes, and which seems to be more proficient?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Theory:

[**PRAM** machines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951522) may harness one of the below listed principal approach to concurrent-events' handling policies not observed in any pure-[**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) system.

Given the nature of the machine physical body, some of the below listed policies may ( but need not ) match the processing goals and software-based tools are then resorts to allow for other policies ( not listed below, thus not supported directly by the [**PRAM**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951522) hardware-based resources ), sure, at a cost of additional time ( add-on overheads ) needed to mediate such policy enforcement steps and measures.

As observed in 3.2.x below, some of the hardware-based policies **may** become directly beneficial for specialised, *not universal*, image processing or similar cases, while a general purpose computing graph does not get correct results, if not protected by some means of exclusivity locking or atomic-operations, as none of the below listed CRCW-policies ensures systematically valid result in otherwise uncoordinated a "just"-[**`[CONCURRENT]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) scheduled code-execution concurrency-originated colliding write-accesses.

---

- **EREW** ( **E**xclusive **R**ead, **E**xclusive **W**rite ):

1.1) Concurrent memory access by multiple processors is not allowed
1.2) If two or more processors try to read from or write to the same memory cell concurrently, the behaviour is **undefined**

---

- **CREW** ( **C**oncurrent **R**ead, **E**xclusive **W**rite ):

2.1) Reading the same memory cell concurrently is OK
2.2) Two concurrent writes to the same cell lead to ***unspecified behaviour***

---

- **CRCW** ( **C**oncurrent **R**ead, **C**oncurrent **W**rite ):

3.1) Concurrent reads and writes are both OK
3.2) Behavior of concurrent writes ***has to be further specified*:**

3.2.1) Weak-CRCW: concurrent write only OK **if** all processors write **0**
3.2.2) Common‐mode-CRCW: all processors need to write **the same value**
3.2.3) Arbitrary‐winner-CRCW: adversary picks one of the values **( a lottery indeed )**
3.2.4) Priority-CRCW: value of **processor with highest ID** is written
3.2.5) Strong-CRCW: **{ largest | smallest }-value** is written

Comment: Plus 100 for including the factors for CRCW and EREW. Really appreciate

Comment: Arbitrary is not a lottery. It does not need to behave stochastically at all for an implementation of this model. It is just an additional *condition for an algorithm* as the algorithm has to never make an assumption about which of the values will be written.

Answer (score 2):

What if two processes attempt to read simultaneously from the same memory location ? (This operation is well defined.)

What if two processes attempt to write simultaneously into the same memory location ? (This operation is not so well defined: will the final value be one written by some of the processes ? If yes, which one ? Will it be a "mixture" ?)

You can design algorithms using one or the other models, i.e. allowing yourself concurrent reads/writes or not.

The most "powerful" machine is the CRCW model, it can give the fastest algorithms, followed by CREW.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation

Comment: With all due respect, the statement "***CRCW model, ... can give the fastest algorithms, followed by CREW.***", by definition, **does NOT hold in general,** except for only a very few **rather very academic** selective cases. Would be scientifically fair to re-articulate the statement, so as to allow it to meet the reality.

Comment: @user3666197: a CRCW can emulate the other models and the converse is not true, this is why it cannot be worse.

Comment: Missed the point. This is not a degree-of-freedom, it is a hardware implementation fact ( not an option ). CRCW has about 5 different strategies what actually happens in a case of a colliding write-access, where **again, it is not a degree-of-freedom** to choose from, but a hardware-based fact, that the code-design has to respect and invent a colliding-write "prevention" ( for the sake of result correctness ), with just one ( if any ) exception when a code may enjoy (just in case of such one particular case indeed happens) blindly rely a **collision-on-write** be MASKED not solved by hardware

Comment: @user3666197: these models are theoretical and assume that memory accesses take constant time. This is not achieved in real machines.