# What is the difference between Work, Span and Time in parallel algorithm analysis?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, time-complexity, analysis, asymptotic-complexity

When analysing parallel algorithms, we tend to focus Work(T1), Span(T∞) or time.

What I'm confused about is that if I was given an algorithm to analyse, what key hints would I need to look for, for Work, span and time?

Suppose this algorithm:
[image]

---

How do I analyse the above algorithm to find the Work, Time and span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Origin:

**PRAM**s have been introduced in early 70-ies last century, in a hope it may allow to jump ahead a performance in tackling computationally hard problems. Yet, the promises or better expectations were cooled down by principal limitations these computing-device architectures still have to live with.

---

### Theory:

**T<sub>1</sub>** = amount of time for a processing, measured once execution done in a pure-[**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) schedule.

**T<sub>∞</sub>** = amount of time for processing a computing-graph ( Directed, ***just hopefully***<sub>often forgotten</sub> finally Acyclic, Graph ) once execution done in a "just"-[**`[CONCURRENT]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) manner, but having an indeed infinite amount of real-resources available all that time, thus allowing for any degree parallelism to actually <sub>but just incidentally</sub> take place.

<sub>( WARNING NOTICE: your professors need not enjoy this interpretation, but reality rules -- infinite processors are simply not enough, as any other resource must also be present in infinite amounts & capabilities, be it RAM-accesses, IO-s, sensorics et al, so that all these must provide infinitely parallel services, avoiding any kind of blocking / waiting / re-scheduling that might have appeared due to any kind of any resource temporal / contextual in-ability to serve as asked, under an infinitely parallel amount of such service-requests, and answer "immediately" )</sub>.

---

### How to tackle:

**T<sub>1</sub>** for the above posted problem has imperatively ordered two O(N) blocks - memory allocations for `M[:]` and final search for `Max` over `M[:]`, and two  O(N<sup>2</sup>) blocks, processing "all pairs" `(i,j)` over a domain of `N`-by-`N` values.

Based on an assumption of a CIS/RIS homogenity, this **Work** will be no less than `~ 2N(1+N)`

For **T<sub>∞</sub>** there would be more things to do. First, detect what potential parallel code-execution paths may happen, next, also protecting the results from being "overwritten" in colliding moments - your headline just slightly mentions CRCW - a weak assumption to analyse the latter problem for a **C**oncurrent-**R**ead-**C**oncurrent-**W**rite **PRAM**-machine.

Do not hesitate to take a pencil, paper and draw the D(jh)AG for the smallest possible **`N == 2`** ( **`3`**, if you have a bit larger paper ), where one can derive the flow of operation ( and potentially (in)-dependency ordering for operations in case of a less forgiving but the more realistic CREW or EREW type of the PRAM-computing-devices ).

---

### Criticism:  <sub>an indeed Devil's part of the Lesson your professors will like the least</sub>

Any careful kind reader has already noted several nontrivial assumptions, a homogenity of CIS/RIS instruction durations being one minor case of these.

The biggest, yet hidden part of the problem, is the actual cost of process-scheduling. A pure-[**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) code execution enjoys ( an unfair ) advantage of having zero add-on overhead costs ( plus on many silicon architectures, there are additional performance tricks arriving from out-of-order instruction re-ordered execution, ref. superscalar pipelined or VLIW architectures for indepth details ), while any sort of real-world process-scheduling principally adds additional overhead costs, that were not present in a pure-[**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) code-execution case for getting the **T<sub>1</sub>**.

On real-world systems, having both NUMA impacted and non-homogeneous CIS/RIS instruction durations impacted remarkable code-execution flow durations' irregularities, these add-on overhead costs indeed dramatically shift the baseline for any speedup comparison.

### The Devil's Question:

**Where** do we account for these real-world  add-on costs?

In real life **we do.**

In original Amdahl's Law formulation and in the Brent's Theorem, **we did not.**

The [**re-formulated Amdahl's Law** inputs also these **`{ initial | coordination | terminal}`**-add-on overhead costs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) and suddenly the computed and experimentally validated speed-ups start to match the observations experienced on the commonly operated real-world computing fabrics.

Comment: Wow! What a depth of knowledge explained very well. It has been a pleasure reading your answer. Regarding `T1 = ~ 2N(1+N)`, could you please explain where 1 + N occurs?

Comment: ( 2 x N + 2 x N^2 ) ~ ( 2 x N + 2 x N x N ) ~ ( 2 x N x ( 1 + N ) )

Comment: Thank you so much!